# Is Git more efficient than Git LFS for large frequently changed text files?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I gather from [Multiple file versions in git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604978/multiple-file-versions-in-git-lfs) that Git LFS stores a full copy of each version of a file even if only a small portion of the file changed. But it's my understanding that Git itself only stores distinct blocks of text and if a new version of a text file is mostly the same as an old version, it would not duplicate the whole file. So if I have a large text file that changes frequently, but usually only a few small pieces of it are changing at a time, am I better of storing it in Git instead of in LFS?

Comment: Git can’t be any worse than Git LFS for this since LFS just stores references (whatever those concretely are). LFS is also another layer ontop of Git. So if you don’t need to able to offload files to LFS remotes? Yes, Git must be better for this. You can then additionally test the deltafication after some number of commits and probably confirm that Git does use deltas on these files as well.

Answer (score 0):

For a **text** file that changes often, you should be fine storing it in Git itself; Git compresses and deltifies text-based formats pretty efficiently, so multiple versions of that large file should store well.

Git LFS is a better fit for binary formats that change often and/or need versioning. (You can still put text files in LFS, though, and if you use a hosting provider with strict size limits then you might have to.)

Comment: I guess the question is if we'd be *better* off storing such a file in Git because it would consume less space overall (all else being equal) versus LFS.

Comment: Assuming the generic case, then yes; instead of N distinct copies, you'd have one copy and a set of (N-1) deltas. The provider limits caveat is still important to call out, though, because a lot of people get caught out by GitHub's 100MiB per-file limit.

Comment: So we are using GitLab and have a file that is 337,000+ lines (22+MB) updated many times a day (usually just a few lines) and have observed that the pipeline is encountering errors while cloning the repository unless we reduce the clone depth from 50 down to 20 or remove this file from the repository's history (repo filter). Is there any performance conclusion to draw for such a file being embedded in the Git repo vs LFS related to these observations?